# How to use JDBC connector with Customized Encryption

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

We have a requirement to use JDBC Connector to read the data from RDBMS and then use our Custom Encryption before pushing data to Kafka. And decrypting the data on the way out and then pushing it to subsequent sinks.

To achieve this, do we need to provide custom implementation of following (part of JDBC Connector Properties) :

```
"key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",    ==>"key.converter": "OurCustomeAvroConverter"
```

OR

do we need to provide custom implementation of following (Part of Producer Configuration Properties):

```
key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer ==> key.serializer = Custom Implementation
```

If it's `key.serializer` then how can we set this property so that it can be picked by JDBC connector ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Kafka connect JDBC connector to push data from DBMS to kafka the official Kafka connect documentation says to use key.convertor and value.convertor properties.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html